# How to avoid suppressing KeyboardInterrupt during garbage collection in python?

Tags: python, linux, exception, garbage-collection, signals

Default handler for SIGINT raises KeyboardInterrupt. However, if a program is inside a __del__ method (because of an ongoing garbage collection), the exception is ignored with the following message printed to stderr:

```
Exception KeyboardInterrupt in <...> ignored
```

As a result, the program continues to work despite receiving SIGINT. Of course, I can define my own handler for SIGINT that sets a global variable sigint_received to True, and then often check the value of the variable in my program. But this looks ugly.

Is there an elegant and reliable way to make sure that the python program gets interrupted after receiving SIGINT?

Answer (score 2):

Before I dive into my solution, I want to highlight the scary red "Warning:" sidebar in the [docs for `object.__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) (emphasis mine):

> Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to `sys.stderr` instead. [...]  **`__del__()` methods should do the absolute minimum needed to maintain external invariants.**

This suggests to me that any `__del__` method that's at serious risk of being interrupted by an interactive user's `Ctrl-C` might be doing too much.  So my first suggestion would be to look for ways to minimize your `__del__` method, whatever it is.

Or to put it another way:  If your `__del__` method really *does* do "the absolute minimum needed", then how can it be safe to kill the process half-way through?

## Custom Signal Handler

The only solution I could find was indeed a [custom signal handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal) for `signal.SIGINT`... but a lot of the obvious tricks didn't work:

### Failed:  `sys.exit`

Calling `sys.exit` from the signal handler just raised a `SystemExit` exception, which was ignored.  Python's C API docs suggest that it is impossible for the Python interpreter to raise *any* exception during a `__del__` method:

> `void`[`PyErr_WriteUnraisable`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_WriteUnraisable)`(PyObject *obj)`
>
> [Called when...] it is impossible for the interpreter to actually raise the exception [...] for example, when an exception occurs in an [`__del__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) method.

### Partial Success:  Flag Variable

Your idea of setting a global "drop dead" variable inside the signal handler worked only partially --- although it updated the variable, nothing got a chance to *read* that variable until after the `__del__` method returned.  So for several seconds, the `Ctrl-C` appeared to have done nothing.

This might be good enough if you just want to terminate the process "eventually", since it *will* exit whenever the `__del__` method returns.  But since you probably want to shut down the process *without* waiting (both `SIGINT` and `KeyboardInterrupt` typically come from an impatient user), this won't do.

### Success:  `os.kill`

Since I couldn't find a way to convince the Python interpreter to kill itself, my solution was to have the (much more persuasive) operating system do it for me.  This signal handler uses [`os.kill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) to send a stronger `SIGTERM` to its own process ID, causing the Python interpreter itself to exit.

```python3
def _sigterm_this_process(signum, frame):
    pid = os.getpid()
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    return

# Elsewhere...
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, _sigterm_this_process)
```

Once the custom signal handler was set,  `Ctrl-C` caused the `__del__` method (and the entire program) to exit immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin.

`__del__` methods in my code come from generators, so there is no way to get rid of them.

Your solution works, but I would also like to do some cleanup before exiting the program. I couldn't do the cleanup in signal handler, because I have no idea which line of the code has been just executed. Besides, I think that what `except KeyboardInterrupt` clause is for. Unfortunately, as I mentioned in my original post it's not reliable.